# Is "no one of them seems grammatical" ungrammatical? Why?

Tags: negation, determiners

I wonder if the following sentence will be grammatical in the most bizarre context:

> **No** one of them seems grammatical.

Clearly, there are way better ways to phrase this sentence, either by using the negative [determinative](http://www.linguisticsgirl.com/the-determinative-in-english-grammar/) "none" or removing the [complement](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/noun-phrases-dependent-words) "of them" or any other way to get sentences like these:

> **None** of them seems grammatical.
>   **No** one seems grammatical.

<sub>Though it's controversial whether the second sentence really works with accordance to semantic rules.</sub>

My intuition also [rightfully] says there should be a ***"not"*** instead of ***"no"*** in order to render the sentence grammatical, or at least revise it to a more colloquial state:

> **Not** one of them seems grammatical.

But the question is, is the original sentence undoubtedly an ungrammatical utterance? If so, why should I use "not" instead of "no"? If both sentences are perfectly acceptable, what possible change in meaning does changing "no" to "not" bring on?

---

<sub>See also ["Neither", "none", "no one" + [of them] + verb-s](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3506/neither-none-no-one-of-them-verb-s) — where the highest-voted answer doesn't choose a clear position regarding a similar structure while a deleted (but fairly highly voted) answer claims it's grammatical.</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phrase *no one of them* is "grammatical" (taking that to mean that it is both idiomatic and meaningful), but it is not always the same thing as *none of them*. It is an emphatic form employed to distinguish a proposition concerning a number of entities taken *singly* from propositions concerning the same entities taken in *combination*.

Consider the difference between these two propositions concerning three people, Adolphus, Benjamin and Carloman, suspected of murdering Dionysius.

> 1. None of them killed him.  *This is taken to assert that all three are innocent of the murder.*
> 2. No one of them killed him. *This implies the possibility that two of them—A and B, or A and C, or B and C—or all three, conspired to commit the murder.*

So it might be perfectly proper to say of three utterances that "No one of them is grammatical" if you intend to propose that some combination of the utterances *is* grammatical.

Comment: Ahh intriguing. I never thought of it like that!